# Is a biconditional statement logically equivalent to its converse?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

According to my truth table, a biconditional is logically equivalent to its converse. Is this correct?

Comment: "Converse" is something we apply to implications: the converse of $P\to Q$ is $Q\to P$. We don't talk about "converse" of other connectives. A biconditional is the conjunction of an implication and its converse.

Comment: Is implication the same as conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ArturoMagidin is right in the Comments: We don't talk about a bi-conditional's converse.

However, I assume you are asking whether $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $Q \leftrightarrow P$, which certainly *looks* like what we do with the normal converse. And yes, those are indeed equivalent.

As such, we can say that the $\leftrightarrow$  is a *commutative* operator, just like the $\land$ and the $\lor$

Comment: Why do we not talk about a biconditionals converse, though? Is it because it's not very common in maths?

Comment: @VedantRana: for the same reason we don't talk about abelian grapes: because "abelian" is not something that applies to grapes at all. Here, because "converse" is not something that applies to "biconditionals", it only applies to implications. Why do we not define "converse" of a biconditional in some way, like "the converse f $P\leftrightarrow Q$ is $Q\leftrightarrow P$"? Because it does not add anything. Same reason we don't talk about the "converse" of "$P\vee Q$" or "the reverse of $P\vee Q$".